# Apply different functions to different columns with a singe pandas groupby command

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My data is stored in `df`. I have multiple `users` per `group`. I want to group `df` by `group` and apply different functions to different columns. The twist is that I would like to assign custom names to the new columns during this process.

```py
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"user":range(4),"group":[1,1,2,2],"crop":["2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-03-01","2018-03-01"],
                   "score":np.random.randint(400,1000,4)})
df["crop"] = pd.to_datetime(df["crop"])
print(df)
   user  group        crop  score
0     0      1  2018-01-01    910
1     1      1  2018-01-01    765
2     2      2  2018-03-01    782
3     3      2  2018-03-01    722
```

I want to get the mean of `score`, and the min and max values of `crop` grouped by `group` **and** assign custom names to each new column. The desired output should look like this:

```py
  group  mean_score    min_crop    max_crop
0     1       837.5  2018-01-01  2018-01-01
1     2       752.0  2018-03-01  2018-03-01
```

I don't know how to do this in a one-liner in Python. In R, I would use `data.table` and get the following:

```
df[, list(mean_score = mean(score),
          max_crop   = max(crop),
          min_crop   = min(crop)), by = group]
```

I know I could group the data and use `.agg` combined with a dictionary. Is there an alternative way where I can custom-name each column in this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a function with the required operations using `groupby().apply()`:

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['mean_score'] = x['score'].mean()
    d['min_crop'] = x['crop'].min()
    d['max_crop'] = x['crop'].max()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['mean_score', 'min_crop', 'max_crop'])

data = df.groupby('group').apply(f)
```