# Groupby and apply different function to each column with first and last

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group the columns then apply different functions to each column. I referred [to the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326349/apply-different-functions-to-different-columns-with-a-singe-pandas-groupby-comma) and my code is as shown below

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['a'] = x['a'].max()
    d['b'] = x['b'].first()
    d['c'] = x['c'].last()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

require_data = required_data.groupby(['S','id', 'lane', 'timestamp','E']).apply(f)
```

And I am getting the following error because of first function

```
TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

But I can run groupby with first fine

```
require_data = required_data.groupby(['S','id', 'lane', 'timestamp','E']).first()
```

What is the cause of the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better here is use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html), there is possible pass columns names with aggregate methods [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)
and 
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
require_data = (required_data.groupby(['S','id', 'lane', 'timestamp','E'])
                             .agg({'a':'max', 'b':'first', 'c':'last'}))
```

If you want to use your own custom function, it's necessary to select by position, with [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html)
or with
[`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html), but like @Erfan mentioned, thank you:

> Using your own custom function is highly discouraged, because of efficiency.

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['a'] = x['a'].max()
    d['b'] = x['b'].iat[0]
    d['c'] = x['c'].iat[-1]
    return pd.Series(d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: I would mention that using your own custom function is highly discouraged, because of efficiency.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for